# I got problem with the socket.io-client not connecting to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-client

I can't connect to the server with socket.io-client

here is how I import socket.io-client
`import io from "socket.io-client`

here I try to connect to io:
`const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")`

then I tried to console log some stuff

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("socket connection established: ", socket.connected)
        const messageInfoLoader = (messageData) => {
          //this messageData is not even logging
          console.log(messageData)
          console.log(messageData.text)
        }

        socket.on("messageInfo", messageInfoLoader)

        socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
  
        return () => {
          socket.off("messageInfo", messageInfoLoader)
          socket.off("connect_error")
        }
      }, [socket])
```

and I also got bunch of those errors:
`polling.js:298     GET http://ws/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OfKIqgW net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

If you know how to fix those please let me know in the comments

when I console log("socket connection established: ", socket.connected), it logs:
socket connection established: false

I tried to add connection rule of that port and still it says socket connection established: false

Comment: update:
I changed import like this:
`import { io } from "socket.io-client"`
and it worked well and there is no more errors, but `socket connection established: false` still occures